# Удалить все div внутри table

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно удалить все div внутри table, я делаю примерно так:

```
$(".ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e").remove();
$(".ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s").remove();
```

и так далее. Можно ли как то обратиться и за раз удалить все div внутри table ?Или же только так по одному можно? Заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нужно удалить все `div` из `table`, то можно так 
`$('table div').remove();`
Если какие-то определенные классы, то можно перечислить сразу все 
 
`$(".ui-resizable-handle .ui-resizable-e, .ui-resizable-handle .ui-resizable-s").remove();`